# Adjust image height according to content height

Tags: jquery, height

I have coded the below jQuery in order to achieve full responsive height of my images which adjusts accordingly with the content height beside it. Please have a look at my code [CodePen](http://codepen.io/audhit/pen/PzPVLM). My problem is, the images are not adjusting their height dynamically whenever I resize my screen width. How can I achieve full dynamic solution of this ? Please help me out if possible.

```
function setImageHeight() {
  $('.single-tile').each(function(){
    var tile_height = $(this).height(); 
    $(this).find('.image').height(tile_height);  
    }
  ); 
}
$(document).ready( function () {
  setImageHeight();
});
$(window).resize( function () {
  setImageHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For responsive height set css property as height:100% and for responsive width set margin:auto. So below css class will do the trick for you.

```
   .responsive-image {
height:100%;
margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, thats not gonna work for me because, my target is to avoid any kind of blank/white space within the content div as well as within the image div...hope u get my point..i achieved exactly what I was looking for, just the screen resizing issue is not working out...anyway thanks for ur reply though..